# Calculate and return the value of 3*f+5*b-15*fb in a FizzBuzzProblem

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

> Given: A number is considered fizz if it is divisible by 3. It is considered buzz if it is divisible by 5. It is considered fizzbuzz if it is divisible by both 3 and 5. A fizzbuzz is neither fizz nor buzz. Given two numbers n1 and n2 such that n2>n1, let f be the number of fizz, b be the number of buzz and fb be the number of fizzbuzz between n1 and n2(both n1 and n2 are included).
>
> Calculate and return the value of 3*f+5*b-15*fb?

**MyApproach**:

I used all conditions given in the question but I am confused how to use this  condition "A fizzbuzz is neither fizz nor buzz"

I am getting wrong output may be because of this Can Anyone guide me how to solve the problem.

```
public int calcFB (int n1, int n2) 
{
    int f=0;
    int b=0;
    int fb=0;
  for(int i=n1;i<=n2;i++)
  {
     if((i%3==0)&&(i%5==0))
     {
       fb++;
     }
     else if(i%3==0)
     {
        f++;
     }
     else if(i%5==0)
     {
        b++;
     }


  }
   return 3*f+5*b+15*fb;

}
```

For the Input:

```
 Parameters      Actual Output  Expected Output
'1' '21'         56             18
```

Comment: In your `return` statement, shouldn't that be *minus*?

Comment: You have a **typo** in the `return` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your return statement, you added 15*fb where in your description of the problem, you said the formula was 3*f+5*b-15*fb. So you need to subtract 15*fb with this return statement:

```
return 3*f+5*b-15*fb
```

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is mostly correct. The phrase `"A fizzbuzz is neither fizz nor buzz"` simply means not to double count numbers in your calculation.

That's because the earlier definitions on their own:

> - A number is considered fizz if it is divisible by 3.
> - It is considered buzz if it is divisible by 5.
> - It is considered fizzbuzz if it is divisible by both 3 and 5.

could be read to (for example) have the number `15` as *all* of `fizz`, `buzz` and `fizzbuzz`, since `15` is *certainly* divisible by both `3` and `5`

The extra phrase clarifies this point, that multiples of `15` are `fizzbuzz` only (neither `fizz` nor `buzz`). And, in fact, your code already *accounts* for this phrase since it checks for `fizzbuzz` first and, if found, moves on to the next number straight away.

---

The reason you're getting the wrong answer is simply that you're *adding* `15*fb` whereas the specs clearly state you need to *subtract* that term:

```
3*f+5*b-15*fb
       ^
       here
```

If you're adding, you get the result `48` (not `56` as you seem to state in the question, that would need the upper end of the range to be `25` rather than `21`). Subtracting will get you the correct answer of `18`.